# Node testing and console.log issues

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've set up a simple node server and test program from the Node: up and running book.  It seems to be working fine when I trace it through with debug but I'm curious why console.log doesn't output anything to the terminal.

**Server, app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000)

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));


var tweets = [];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to Node Twitter');
});

app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
if (req.body && req.body.tweet) {
    tweets.push(req.body.tweet);
    res.send({status:"ok", message:"Tweet received"});
} else {
    // no tweet ?
    res.send({status:"nok", message:"No tweet received"});
}
});

app.get('tweets', function (req, res) {
res.send(tweets);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**Test script, test.js**

```
var http = require('http');
assert = require('assert');

var opts = {
host: 'localhost',
port: 8000,
path: '/send',
method: 'POST',
headers: {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}   
}   

var req = http.request(opts, function(res) {
res.setEncoding('utf8');

console.log("Sending test");

var data = "";
res.on('data', function(d) {
    data += d;
})



res.on('end', function() {
    assert.strictEqual(data, '{"status":"ok", "message":"Tweet received"}');
    console.log("test");

})
})

req.write('tweet=test')
req.end
```

Would love some advice.

Comment: Is this working? `console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));`

Comment: What console - there are two apps (Server and test client), which one is not outputting ? Also express has its own http server

Comment: Apologies, the console.log statement in the test.js file don't work.  The one in app.js works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event `end` never gets fired because you don't call the function `req.end`. You maintains the http request/connection open. You never finish it.

Try instead:

```
req.end();
```

Think about the difference between:

```
console.log('HI');
console.log;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Stupid mistake.